# Wrapping C-enum in a Python module with Swig

Tags: python, c, swig

I have a simple enum in C in myenum.h:

```
enum MyEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
```

The problem is that when I map this to Python, I can only access the enum through the module name, not through MyEnum. So the values ONE, TWO, THREE are included with any other functions I define, instead of being contained with MyEnum.

My api.i file is:

```
%module api
%{
#include "myenum.h"
%}
%include "myenum.h"
```

I generate with SWIG

```
swig -builtin -python api.i
```

And import it into Python

```
import _api
```

And now I have to use the enum values from the _api module:

```
_api.ONE
_api.TWO
_api.THREE
```

While I want to use them like

```
_api.MyEnum.ONE
_api.MyEnum.TWO
_api.MyEnum.THREE
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Thd _api module is private. You shouldn't be using it directly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a SWIG feature [**nspace**](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nspace) that would do want you want, but unfortunately it isn't supported for Python yet.  I've always had to define the enum in a struct for it to show up in the manner you desire in SWIG.  Example:

```
%module tmp

%inline %{
struct MyEnum {
    enum { A,B,C };
};
%}
```

Result:

```
>>> import tmp
>>> tmp.MyEnum.A
0
>>> tmp.MyEnum.B
1
>>> tmp.MyEnum.C
2
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is that in C those names in your enum are not namespaced as they would be in Python. You should probably read something about how [enums can be used](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/enum.html) before continuing.

Now note that since those are globally accessible names, they will not be namespaced in Python. Your best bet, is to create an object, along these lines:

```
class MyEnum:
   A = A
   B = B
   C = C

del(A, B, C)
```

Then A, B, C will only be accessible through `_api.MyEnum.A`, etc., and A, B, C won't be directly accessible.